# Dynamically choose table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

There are two tables with the same structure (same columns, same column names, etc).

How can I design a query so that a certain table is queried from, depending on a variable?

```
DECLARE @MYVAR SMALLINT = 0;

DECLARE @TABLENAME VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @TABLENAME = CASE WHEN @MYVAR = 1 THEN 'TABLE1' ELSE 'TABLE2' END

SELECT @TABLENAME

-- HOW TO DYNAMICALLY SELECT TABLE NAME HERE?
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @TABLENAME
```

[Technet docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104(v=sql.105).aspx) hint at maybe using a table alias here, but the [examples](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187731(v=sql.105).aspx) don't show anything related to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, you need to build query dynamically and execute it

```
DECLARE @MYVAR SMALLINT = 0;

DECLARE @TABLENAME VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @TABLENAME = CASE WHEN @MYVAR = 1 THEN 'TABLE1' ELSE 'TABLE2' END

declare @sql  = 'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM '+ quotename(@TABLENAME)

Exec (@sql) -- To execute the query that is built dynamically
```

Answer (score 2):

Beside the obvious solution with dynamic SQL (which you would need especially if your column lists might **not** be the same) you can go like this:

```
DECLARE @tblName VARCHAR(100)='tbl1';

SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM tbl1
WHERE @tblName='tbl1'
UNION ALL
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM tbl2
WHERE @tblName='tbl2'
```

The biggest advantage was, that this approach is inlineable, can be used as `VIEW` or better as `inline TVF`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep it in plain SQL (without the procedural part) it can be done like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE @MYVAR = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE @MYVAR = 0
```

SQL Server should be smart enough to evaluate one of the conditions as "always false" and skip reading the other table. Consult `EXPLAIN` to confirm that.